# how to get size dropdown on specific page where we required for example on clothing,footwear

Tags: php, mysql

How to get size dropdown on specific page where we required for example on clothing, footwear
and not on all the pages.by this coding we are getting dropdown on all the pages and when we 
select size it should go to `temorderdetails` detdatabase.when we select size from dropdown
and send all size are shown in database

**product.php**

```
<?php 
//Check to see the URL variable is set and that it exists in the database
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id=preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i','',$_GET['id']);
    //Use this var to check to see if this ID exists, if yes then get the product
    //details, if no then exit this script and give message 
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 50");
    $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);//count the output amount
    if($productCount > 0){
        //get all the product details
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            $product_name   =   $row["product_name"];
            $price          =   $row["price"];
            $merchant_id    =   $row["merchant_id"];
            $details        =   $row["details"];
            $typ_id         =   $row["typ_id"];
            $cat_id         =   $row["cat_id"];
            $sub_id         =   $row["sub_id"];
            $qty            =   $row["qty"];
            $size1          =   $row["size1"];
            $size2          =   $row["size2"];
            $size3          =   $row["size3"];
            $size4          =   $row["size4"];
            $size5          =   $row["size5"];
            $product_img2   =   $row["product_img2"];
            $product_img3   =   $row["product_img3"];
            $date_added     =   strftime("%b %d, %Y",strtotime($row["date_added"]));         
        }
    }else{
        $dynamicList .= "That item doesnot exit."; 
        exit();
    }

}else{
    echo "Data to render this page is missing.";  
    exit();
}

mysql_close();
?>

<select name="size" id="size">
    <option>Select a Size</option>
    <option value="$size1"><?php echo $size1; ?></option><br/>
    <option value="$size2"><?php echo $size2; ?></option><br/>
    <option value="$size3"><?php echo $size3; ?></option><br/>
    <option value="$size4"><?php echo $size4; ?></option><br/>
    <option value="$size5"><?php echo $size5; ?></option><br/>
</select>
```

Database of `temporderdetails`

```
id      product_name    details                 price       qty     size1   size2   size3   size4       size5   total       omid    name    
134     canon           fyuytu                  10000.00    0                                                   10000.00    1   
142     samsung         tab cgbfh               30000.00    0                                                   30000.00    1
137     titen           sdfsf                   1000.00     0                                                   1000.00     2   
140     kurti           fgfcgh                  300.00      0                                                   300.00      2   
178     Fastrack        <p>Asrfsgfdgfg</p>      9990.00     1       0       0       0       0                   9990.00     4   
185     Tab             <p>Afrdetfgdghjh</p>    20000.00    1       0       0       0       0                   20000.00    4
```

How to get size dropdown on specific page where we required for example on clothing,footwear
and not on all the pages? By this coding we are getting dropdown on all the pages and when we 
select size it should go to `temorderdetails` detdatabase.when we select size from dropdown
and send all size are shown in database.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, your while should store all rows separately and need to look more like:

```
<?php
//Check to see the URL variable is set and that it exists in the database
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id     =   preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i','',$_GET['id']);
    //Use this var to check to see if this ID exists, if yes then get the product
    //details, if no then exit this script and give message 
    $sql    =   mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 50");
    $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);//count the output amount
    if($productCount > 0){
        //get all the product details
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            // Store all the rows in an array
            $result[]       =   $row;        
        }
    }else{
        $dynamicList .= "That item doesnot exit."; 
        exit();
    }

}else{
    echo "Data to render this page is missing.";  
    exit();
}

mysql_close();
```

How to access each row and data:

```
// Loop through the row array and echo form elements (I only demonstrated select and 1 text input here)
foreach($result as $data) { ?>
        <input type="text" name="product_name[]" value="<?php echo $data['product_name']; ?>" />
        <select name="size[]">
            <option value="<?php echo $data['size1']; ?>"><?php echo $data['size1']; ?></option>
            <option value="<?php echo $data['size2']; ?>"><?php echo $data['size2']; ?></option>
            <option value="<?php echo $data['size3']; ?>"><?php echo $data['size3']; ?></option>
            <option value="<?php echo $data['size4']; ?>"><?php echo $data['size4']; ?></option>
            <option value="<?php echo $data['size5']; ?>"><?php echo $data['size5']; ?></option>
        </select>
        <?php
    }
```

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
         $result['product_name'] = $row;
   $result['price']=$row;      is this array ok or we should change it to other

Comment: Since you are generating multiple rows, each containing the `size` columns you generate the drop down selections for, you have to first store the rows then loop through them and produce blocks of inputs based on each stored row. Also, I am not 100% sure what you are looking for so my answer is a guess based on info you have provided.

Comment: we want dropdown of size which is coming from database we want to show it on particular product with help of id as shown in data base,we are not able to understant  // Store all the rows in an array
            $result[]       =   $row;        please explain with code